# common letters in two strings

Tags: python, string

I've been trying to solve this program which takes two strings as input and outputs number of common letters. For Example, if the input was "common" and "connor" then the output should be 4 ( 1 c , 1 n and 2 o's ).I used set() function but it outputs 3 ( it treats both o's as a single common letter ). Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!!!

Btw here's the code i wrote:

```
print("Enter number of inputs: ")
c = int(input())
store = []
for each_item in range(c):
    print("Enter First String: ")
    one = input()
    print("Enter Second String")
    two = input()
    s = len(set(one) & set(two))
    store.append(s)
for each_number in store:
    print(each_number)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter

>>> Counter('common')
Counter({'m': 2, 'o': 2, 'c': 1, 'n': 1})
>>> Counter('connor')
Counter({'o': 2, 'n': 2, 'c': 1, 'r': 1})

>>> common = Counter('common') & Counter('connor') # intersection
>>> common
Counter({'o': 2, 'c': 1, 'n': 1})
>>> sum(common.values())
4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do list comprehension for that too

```
>>> a = 'common'
>>> b = 'connor'
>>> sum([1 for l in a if l in b])
4
```

**EDIT**

```
a,b = 'come','common'

def collision_count(a,b):
    da = {l:a.count(l) for l in a}
    db = {l:b.count(l) for l in b}
    return sum(min(v,db[k]) for k,v in da.items() if k in db.keys())

print collision_count(a,b)
3
```

Are you now ok with that?

Comment: You could have made it a generator expression :)

Comment: And its `O(N^2)`. That can be simplified like this `sum(l in b for l in a)`

Comment: That didnt work either. I've just tried by taking 'common', 'come' and the answer was 4 instead of 3